# GRANT statements with bound parameters

Tags: postgresql

I'm using a client library that only accepts SQL strings that are compile-time constant, in order to prevent SQL injection attacks. And I wanted to execute some GRANT statements for a set of tables and a user.

I tried

`GRANT SELECT ON $1 TO $2`

and passing the table and user names as bound parameters. But that fails with

`syntax error at or near "$1"`

Not being able to pass in a tablename as a bound parameter is understandable (you can't use `SELECT columns FROM $1` for instance), and with a bit of work, I can make the tablenames compile-time constants. But changing the command to

`GRANT SELECT ON MyTable to $1`

and passing just the username as a bound parameter also fails. Which is more of an issue: whereas the tablenames can be hard-coded with a bit of work, the username is only known at runtime.

Is there a way to pass the username as a bound parameter, or do I need to bypass my client library in order to GRANT permissions to a run-time-defined username?

Comment: You need to cross-verify user input in all cases even if bound parameters available. It's not only SQL injections but logical injection too. Imagine SQL grant indeed accepts parameters and you execute `as user U1 grant select on $1 to user $2=U2` without verifying.

Comment: Thanks, fukanchik, but in this case the usernames are coming from a trusted source, just not at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_grant (_role text)
    RETURNS void
    AS $$
DECLARE
    _sql text := '';
BEGIN
    _sql := 'GRANT SELECT ON a to ' || quote_ident(_role) || ' GRANTED BY current_user ';
    RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;
    EXECUTE _sql;
    RAISE NOTICE '% granted table a to %', CURRENT_USER, _role;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
STRICT.
```

You can also make the table as function input argument. quote_ident is used for identifiers quoting. In `GRANT SELECT ON MyTable to $1` you hope to make sure $1 is a identifiers rather than some string. Because if $1 string then the whole  command can be:
`GRANT SELECT ON MyTable to public;`
`GRANT SELECT ON MyTable to role_a  WITH GRANT OPTION;`
So the above function can solve these problem.

Comment: That should do the trick, cheers

Answer (score 0):

The only statements that can use parameters are `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `SELECT`. `GRANT` cannot use parameters; you will have to build a statement dynamically.